# Is it okay to format my Toshiba Canvio Ready Portable Hard Drive to "ext4"?

Tags: hard-disk, ext4, ntfs, hfs+

Today I have bought a new [Toshiba 1TB Canvio Ready USB 3.0 Portable External Hard Drive (Black)](http://www.mytoshiba.com.au/products/storage/portable-hard-drives/hdtp210ak3aa/overview). The [specifications page of the portable hard drive](http://www.mytoshiba.com.au/products/storage/portable-hard-drives/hdtp210ak3aa/specifications) says, it has been formated to **NTFS** file system and can be re-formatted to **HFS+** file system for full Mac compatibility.

> **File system** 
>   NTFS (MS Windows) 
>   * The drive can be re-formatted to HFS+ file system for full Mac compatibility.

However, I am a GNU/Linux user and I am wishing to re-format the portable external hard drive to **ext4** file system. Is it okay to do so?

Comment: As far as I know, all hard drives can be formatted for any file system (with some minor exceptions)

Comment: I have used many SATA, IDE hard disk drives before. But this is for the first time I am using a portable hard drive. I'll be using this to keep all my important data. So, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Portable hard drives are just regular hard drives with SATA to USB converters. Some will even let you put your own SATA hard drive in there. Do note: some adapters do not power the hard drive enough. Like always: Check the Manual

Comment: Unfortunately the manual doesn't contain too many informations other than the informations mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. The only reason that only NTFS and HFS+ were mentioned was because that's what the vast majority of people purchasing their product are going to use.

This isn't OS-specific, but I would strongly recommend that you always make sure to properly unmount the drive before you disconnect the USB cable. USB drives aren't always as fast as internal drives, and if you disconnect the cable before the drive has completed writing you'll potentially lose data!

Comment: Thanks. This question came to my mind, because I had formatted the portable hard drive to **ext4**, copied some files to it  and then tried to unmount it. I tried to unmount it using GNOME Files (Nautilus), but it said that it couldn't unmount the drive. It made me think that, something is wrong. But after reading your answer, it seems to me that the computer was busy writing to the portable hard drive, even after completing copying. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Yes. Unless the partition is mounted with the `sync` option (which really slows down disk writes!), data are buffered and written out a bit later.